# Validate user-supplied data without form in Angular

Tags: angularjs, json, validation, object

I'm working on a project where the user can not only add data by a form, but also by uploading a CSV, which gets converted to JSON and then posted to the backend as if it were a submitted form.

However, all Angular validation documentation is about forms. Is there a way to have a single validation logic and apply it on both the form and plain JS objects as well?

Comment: You can always implement your own validation service